# Grails GORM self-referential one-to-many throws LazyInitializationException in Groovy Console

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I assume that the issue involves the creation of the Groovy console inside the Grails instance; normal Domain object queries work fine, but attempting to query into a self-referential one-to-one causes issues.

I have a Domain class like the followng:

```
package demo

class Foo {
    String name
    static hasMany = [substitutes: Foo]
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

During `bootstrap`, I create a Console to be able to inspect the domain objects:

```
import demo.Foo
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplication
import grails.util.GrailsUtil
import groovy.ui.Console

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        def one = new Foo([name: 'one'])
        def two = new Foo([name: 'two'])
        [one,two].each { it.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)}
        one.addToSubstitutes(two)
        one.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

        def appCtx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext)
        def grailsApp = appCtx.getBean(GrailsApplication.APPLICATION_ID);
        Binding b = new Binding();
        b.setVariable("ctx", appCtx);
        def console = new Console(grailsApp.classLoader, b);
        console.run()

        Foo.list().each{println it.name} 
        Foo.list().each{println it.substitutes} 
        println '--------------------------'
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

This prints the following in the console:

```
one
two
[demo.Foo : 2]
null
--------------------------
```

Within the console, I attempt to repeat the two queries, which throws an exception:

```
groovy> import demo.Foo 
groovy> demo.Foo.list().each{println it.name} 
groovy> demo.Foo.list().each{println it.substitutes} 

one
two
Exception thrown

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: demo.Foo.substitutes, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:368)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:186)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at ConsoleScript2$_run_closure2.doCall(ConsoleScript2:3)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at ConsoleScript2.run(ConsoleScript2:3)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
```